# Custom Navigation Bar in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

How can I set Navigation Bar Looks as Follow:

[image]

*I have images for White Triangle Only.*

How can i set background like Bar button of that images??

Comment: make a custom navigation bar...

Comment: How can i make custom navigation bar

Comment: Subclass it. There are many tutorials for that over internet

Comment: can you suggest any reference.

Comment: See the following [Question 1][1] and the following: [Question 2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672229/how-to-subclass-uinavigationbar-for-a-uinavigationcontroller-programatically
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878664/subclassing-uinavigationbar-how-do-i-use-it-in-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: can we set using bar button??

Comment: is there any other way rather than custom navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the title view of your navigation item to a segmented control. Then set the image of the segments to your arrows.

You can do the whole interface in your xib or storyboard. Just drag a segmented control over the title in your view controller.